# Detect press of alt key with pynput keyboard

Tags: python, keyboard, pynput

I am trying to hold down the alt key when I press it with [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/). I checked the documentation and could not find a list saying how to call all specific keys or detect all specific keys. So that sucks.

I've used their cookie-cutter code for detecting presses to try and detect keys:

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

```
def on_press(key):
    print('{0} pressed'.format(
        key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} release'.format(
        key))
    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

but when I try to modify it like this...

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('Alphanumeric key pressed: {0} '.format(
            key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key pressed: {0}'.format(
            key))

def on_release(key):
    print('Key released: {0}'.format(
        key))
    if key == keyboard.Key.alt_1: <------ this
        print('test')

# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

It just quits when I attempt to press `alt` or any key I select for the if statement.

Ideally, I'd like to do this:

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_release(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.alt_1:
        keyboard.press.alt_1

# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

but obviously, I can't even reach this point. Help?

Comment: why do you use `.alt_1` instead of `.alt` ? There is no `.alt_1` and it may raise error and quit code. If I use `if key == keyboard.Key.alt:` then code works for me.

Comment: there is no `keyboard.press.alt_1` but `pynput.keyboard.Controller().press(pynput.keyboard.Key.alt)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you use `alt_1` instead of `alt`.

And if you want to send some key then you have to use `Controller()`

This code works for me

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener, Controller

def on_press(key):
    print(f'{key} pressed')

def on_release(key):
    print(f'{key} released')

    if key == Key.alt:
        print('>>> I press ALT <<<')
        controller.press(Key.alt)

    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

#--- main ---

controller = Controller()

# Collect events until released
with Listener(on_press=on_press,on_release=on_release) as listener:
    # ... other code ...
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

I just use below. All small letter.

```
if key == key.alt :
```

worked for me. In my case, I wanted to use f7 key, so it was `key.f7`.